# Select element on 2nd window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to always prevent the default function of a button on a shopping cart.

The problem is, is the cart is loaded after the original page is ready. I've been using jQuery `ajaxComplete` and it works some of the time, just not all the time. Is there someway to select a button on a page rendered after the original document has loaded?

This is my code that works about 80% of the time.

```
mine();
function mine(){
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
    console.log("got in here");
    $("form[action='/cart']").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("hell yea");
    });
  });  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `$(document).ready(function() { })`.

Comment: `it works some of the time` - what happens when it doesn't work? you mention "second window" - what do you mean by this? code run in one window has no impact on some "second window" unless it specifically targets this "second window" - and the code you've shown does not